# $(this).find(".text") and (".loading") inside a AJAX success function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've been searching Stack Overflow for well over an hour now and can't seem to find a solution to this problem. To reduce loading time on this PHP page I'm trying to place content from other pages into a div.

The page queries correctly and I can see the output in Safari (Inspector) and FireBug.

The content inside the `success: function(output_string)` will not load. I have tried every possible combination. I have also attempted `var self = this;` with no luck although I think this may be due to `jQuery(document).ready(function() {` But I am using 2 versions of jQuery.

Here's my attached code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".text").hide();
  //toggle the component with class msg_body
  jQuery(".ttop2").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).next(".text").slideToggle(500);

    var expanded = "./expand.png";
    var collapsed = "./collapse.png";
    var src = $(this).find(".toggle").attr('src');

<? if($show == 'off') { ?>

    if (src == expanded){
      $(this).find(".toggle").attr('src',collapsed);
      var office = $(this).attr("id");
      var month = "<? echo $month; ?>";
      var year = "<? echo $year; ?>";
      $(this).closest(".loading").html("Loading...");
      alert(office);

      $.ajax({
        url: 'LTData.php',
        type:'POST',
        data: 'office=' + office + '&month=' + month + '&year=' + year,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output_string){
            $(this).find(".loading").html("");
            $(this).find(".text").html(output_string);
        } // End of success function of ajax form
      }); // End of ajax call 

    } else {
      $(this).find(".toggle").attr('src',expanded);
      var office = $(this).attr("id");
      alert(office);
    }

  });
});

<? } else {
//..... Etc.
 ?>
```

P.S: I started Javascript programming today so I would love some critical responses. Thanks!

Edit: Script is in the head.

Edit 2: Attached HTML/PHP.

```
    $sqlb="SELECT * FROM league ORDER by total DESC"; 
    $resultb=mysql_query($sqlb);
    $num=mysql_num_rows($resultb);
    while($rowsb=mysql_fetch_array($resultb)){

    if($rowsb[total] == '0') {
        continue;
    }


if($col=='ebdff2'){

$col='efefef';

}else{

$col='ebdff2';

}
?>

<table class="ttop2" id="<? echo $rowsb["office"]; ?>" bgcolor="#<? echo $col;?>" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="50%" align="left"><b style="text-transform: capitalize; color:rgb(98, 188, 70);"><? echo $rowsb[office];?></b></td>
        <td width="20%" align="left"><b style="text-transform: capitalize; color:rgb(98, 188, 70);"><? echo $rowsb[leads];?></b></td>
        <!-- <td width="200px" align="left">Total leads</td>
        <td width="270px" align="left">Leads converted</td>-->
        <td width="20%" align="left"><b style="text-transform: capitalize; color:rgb(98, 188, 70);"><? echo $rowsb[total];?></b></td>
        <td width="10%" align="left"><img style="float: right;" class="toggle" alt="" src="./expand.png" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div class="text"><div class="loading"></div></div>

<? } ?>

<?
}///end of show what...
?>
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, $(this) within an AJAX call would refer to the call itself and not the element that was clicked.

Comment: I'm a novice to AJAX. If anyone could provide an alternative to load external MySQL into a div I would be happy to try the setup. :) For now, AJAX has been the only possible way I can see

Comment: Define your clicked attribute at the top, `var button = $(this);` so that you can use it throughout.

Comment: I assigned a var for $(this) and for = this; - No joy. Think it is because I'm using 2 copies of jQuery?     Edit: Code in comments is not my strong point :P

Comment: You realize `for` means something special in javascript, right?

Comment: Yes, if I could figure out how to use [code] I may be able to show that I meant '= this; and = $(this);'

Comment: wrap it in ` to show code. (top left key on keyboard, below esc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the ajax success function, you lose you `this` reference. You need to cache it before the function :

```
var $this = $(this); //Here
$.ajax({
    url: 'LTData.php',
    type:'POST',
    data: 'office=' + office + '&month=' + month + '&year=' + year,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(output_string){
        $this.find(".loading").html("");
        $this.find(".text").html(output_string);
    } // End of success function of ajax form
}); // End of ajax call
```

Or, as Kevin B said, pass it in the context option :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'LTData.php',
    type:'POST',
    data: 'office=' + office + '&month=' + month + '&year=' + year,
    dataType: 'json',
    context : this,
    success: function(output_string){
        $(this).find(".loading").html("");
        $(this).find(".text").html(output_string);
    } // End of success function of ajax form
}); // End of ajax call
```

Comment: Or alternatively pass it through the `context` option.

Comment: Okay, I now have another issue.. The '.loading' and '.text' aren't in the same div. I may need to use a 'child' or 'parent' or something. Any ideas?

Comment: yeah, .parent() or .closest() would probably get you there.

Comment: `$(this).next('.text').html(output_string).find('.loading').empty()`  should do the job of your 2 lines.

Comment: No joy with that either :/

Comment: The question that you asked is answered, can you accept the answer and open up a new question with your new question?

Comment: Problem with the loading in this one too.. Need to select the text div and then change .loading?
      $(this).find(".toggle").attr('src',collapsed);
      var office = $(this).attr("id");
      var month = "<? echo $month; ?>";
      var year = "<? echo $year; ?>";
      $(this).find(".loading").html("Loading...");
      alert(office);

Comment: $(this).next('.text').html(output_string).find('.loading').empty() Did not work correctly either. I would be grateful if someone could possibly take a look at my HTML and have a look which code I should be using

Comment: Since `this` is the table `.ttop2`, the code provided should work : http://jsfiddle.net/XRkvS/

Answer (score 0):

after

```
 jQuery(".ttop2").click(function() {
```

do

```
var parent = $(this);
```

and replace all your calls to $(this) with parent. You are having a lot of enclosure issues with the use of $(this) so fix this first and let us know if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

The below code needs to be written under success event, where response is the returned data in html.

```
//use filter to find an element is at the root level of response.

  if ($(response).filter('#Display').length > 0) { }

//use find to search an element is not at the root level of response.

  if ($(response).find('#AddNew').length > 0) { }
```

Comment: I don't have any of those Divs?

Comment: @user2733349 give the above code a try by replacing what you want to search and if its more than 1 you can use each to loop through them and then doing someting using `this` keyword. Those divs in my code is just a sample. I am sure you are capable enough to change those with your needs!

Comment: It's all too confusing! :P Im guessing `$this` or `.ttop2`? 

`if ($(response).filter('???').length > 0) {
   $this.next('.text').append(output_string).find('.loading').empty();
}`